# Overwrite entry.title in template

Tags: entries

Does anybody know if it is possible to overwrite entry.title in a template?

The following 2 options causes errors:

```
{% set entry.title = 'value' %}
{% set entry['title'] = 'value' %}
```

Comment: You can't save entries using the Model in a template. What would be the use case for this?

Comment: Why didn't you use a custom "title" variable throughout your template instead of overriding the entry's title?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The use case is: there is a page (match detail for a sportsclub) which isn't an entry, but with a route I use a template. The data comes from xml. In the template I get the entry data from the 'parent' entry. And I wanted to overwrite the entry.title with the Match title. 
But I founded an other solution for this. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 5):

It's my understanding that [Twig's set tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html) can only be used on variables.

But in your case `entry` is an object and `title` is it's [property](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

You could however create a work-around:

```twig
{% set my_title = 'New' %}
{{ my_title is defined ? my_title : entry.title }}
```

If `my_title` is defined it will be outputted.